# Elementary syntax question

Tags: function-construction, syntax

With the function

```
P[n_] :=  Module[{s,t} , 
    s = Sum[z^k/k!, {k, 0,Infinity}];
    t = Series[s^x, {z, 0, n+1}];
    f[x_] = n!^2 Coefficient[t, z, n]
]
```

I get for

```
Map[P[3], {0, 1}]

{(6 x^3)[0],(6 x^3)[1]}
```

What I want is {0, 6}, the x evaluated at {0,1}. How to do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In at least this case, you might consider using `SeriesCoefficient[]` instead:

```
P[n_Integer?NonNegative] := Block[{x, z},
  Function[x, n!^2 SeriesCoefficient[Exp[z]^x, {z, 0, n}] // Evaluate]]

P[3] /@ {0, 1}
   {0, 6}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
P[n_]:=Module[{s,t},
    s=Sum[z^k/k!,{k,0,Infinity}];
    t=Series[s^x,{z,0,n+1}];
    Function@@{x,n!^2 Coefficient[t,z,n]}
]

P[3] /@ {0, 1}
```

> {0, 6}

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the `f=...` isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks. But how to do it with Map[]?

Comment: `P[3] /@ {0, 1}` and `Map[P[3], {0, 1}]` are syntactically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use Carl Woll's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147177/11035).  However, the following approach might be more intuitive to a new user.

You could allow `P[n]` to take an argument `x` :

```
ClearAll[P]    
P[n_][x_] := Module[{s, t}, 
  s = Sum[z^k/k!, {k, 0, Infinity}];
  t = Series[s^x, {z, 0, n + 1}];
  n!^2 Coefficient[t, x, n]
   ]
```

Then:

```
Map[ P[3], {0,1} ]
```

> ```
> {0, 6}
> ```

Note that the `Module` will re-evaluate for each different `x` call.  Avoiding this is possible (as Carl Woll does), but the syntax gets a bit more messy.